# Разные формы репутации

Tags: дефект, локализация, репутация, профиль-участника

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должна быть разная форма (one, few, many). В данном случае **репутации**.

Comment: Строку в транзифекс искали? Если там единственная форма, то нужно писать на MSE с тегом [plurals].

Comment: @alexolut только  8d9bec4f224970e231041639de877092  и  6fed0ce6808435a1b1cff1c17a4c957a  видел. https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40266952?q=key%3A6fed0ce6808435a1b1cff1c17a4c957a

Comment: тут еще надо бы [формат дат](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290392/339911) принять во внимание.

Comment: Да что-то вообще криво сформулировано

Comment: @alexolut https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315496/260198

Comment: Вообще-то тут должны быть «баллы репутации»

Comment: @alexolut или "очки репутации".

Comment: @Suvitruf “монокли” :) «Баллы» уже приняты для использования в таких контекстах. Очки — нет.

Comment: @alexolut попрошу, сударь...